# Find the zeros of the function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find the poles of $f(z)$

$f(z)= \left( 1+z^4 \right)^1$

I tried to separate $\left( i+z^2 \right) \left( i+z^2 \right)$ but I need to find for the other two poles.
I tried also $\left( 1+z^2 \right)= \left(z+\sqrt{i} \right) \left( z-\sqrt{i} \right )$.
I need a hint.

Comment: Hint: try solving $z^4=-1 \iff z^2= \pm i$ by considering its geometrical interpretation

Comment: Thank you, now i understood. It is the first part of the problem.Actually i have to calculate the integral. So i was trying to find the poles, then the residue and then the integral. He used pi/4 because it is in complex Euler notation. but of course when cos(pi/4)+isen(pi/4) =1/sqrt(2)+1/sqrt(2) and with your hint i got -1 and it is my first zero.

Comment: As JeongNam-ho pointed out, there is a mistake in your formulation of the problem. You must mean $f(z)= \frac{1}{1+z^4}$, otherwise the function has no poles, only roots.

Comment: yes my friend, is ^-1, are poles.

Answer (score 1):

The roots of the polynomial are only $\sqrt{i}$ and $- \sqrt{i}$. That's all!
They are just repeated.

Comment: thank you. My professor gave me the answer. 4 poles and are when z=e^i(pi/4) and z=e^-i(pi/4) then z=e^i(3pi/4) and z=e^-i(3pi/4). But i dont understand how he did.

Comment: You said, f was a polynomial...

Comment: I think, the fuction $f$ must be $1/(z^4-1)$.